# Visual Basic - VBA code to skip or ignore rule if cell contains certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, code, visual-basic

I have written the following VBA code to automatically populate column "P" with "pending", "Not due","-" based on the value of column "O".

The user will manually have to enter "complete" into column "P" if the task is done. This is not auto populated.

I need to make sure that last rule (if column O is "yes", then enter "pending into column P) is skipped if column "P" already says "Complete".

Can anyone help me please? Fairly urgent. Thanks!

```
Sub info()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 11 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).row
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 15) = "No" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("P" & i) = "Not due"
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 11 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).row
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 15) = "-" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("P" & i) = "-"
        End If
    Next i
    **For i = 11 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).row
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 15) = "Yes" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("P" & i) = "Pending"
        End If**
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Your Code returns nothing, could you just write me in which Cells of Column P you have written No , - & Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by adding an additional IF check. I've also optimized the code by going from 3 loops to 1 loop, so the code is 3 times faster, and placed the 3 checks into one select case so it reads easier.

Your code would look something like this:

```
Sub info()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 11 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).row

        Select case ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 15)
            Case is "No"
                ActiveSheet.Range("P" & i) = "Not due"

            Case is "-"
                ActiveSheet.Range("P" & i) = "-"

            Case is "Yes"
                If not ActiveSheet.Range("P" & i) = "Complete" then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("P" & i) = "Pending"
                End if

        End Select

    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**You may try this VBA Code also.**

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("P1:P3")

 For Each r In rng
   v = r.Value

     If v = "No" Then
       r.Offset(5, 1).Value = "Not Due"
     End If

     If v = "-" Then
       r.Offset(5, 1).Value = "- -"
     End If

     If v = "Yes" Then
       If r.Offset(5, 1).Value = "Complete" Then Exit Sub
       r.Offset(5, 1).Value = "Pending"

     End If

 Next r

End Sub
```

**NB:** *You Input Range for **No**, **-** and **Yes** is P1:P3.*

First Click will populate Cell O6:O8 with **Not Due**, **--** and **Pending**.

*As soon you write **Complete** in Cell O8, this Code will skip Cell O8.*

**Note,** You can alter the Input Range and Cell Offset position.

*Hope this Help You.*

**Remember I've posted this Solution after it was Tested by me. If anybody disagreed with all this, WRITE THE REASON before DOWN VOTE.**

Comment: Not helpful. The original code clear uses columns O and P on the same row (with the row starting from 11), but your code uses rows 1 to 3 for column P and rows 6-8 for column O. Also - consider the use of `Select Case` for the multiple `If` statements.